# How delete road labels in google maps Api v3?

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I would like to delete the blue roads labels.... 
How is possible with Api v3 ?

I use this:

```
    var mapDiv = document.getElementById('map_canvas');
    var myOptions = {
        zoom: 11,
        center: new google.maps.LatLng(42.705,13.25),
        mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP,
        mapTypeControl: true,
        zoomControl: true
    };
    map = new google.maps.Map(mapDiv, myOptions);
```

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should be able to disable road labels on your google map by executing this piece of code:

```
map.setOptions({
        styles: [
                {"featureType": "road.highway",elementType: "labels",stylers:[{visibility: "off"}]}, //turns off highway labels
                {"featureType": "road.arterial",elementType: "labels",stylers: [{visibility: "off"}]}, //turns off arterial roads labels
                {"featureType": "road.local",elementType: "labels",stylers: [{visibility: "off"}]}  //turns off local roads labels
         ]
});
```

For details, see [Google Maps Styles Reference](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/style-reference). Also, this [wizard](http://googlemaps.github.io/js-samples/styledmaps/wizard/index.html) can be helpful when playing with map styles, since you can just copy the generated JSON into your code.